How to get text to align between controls in WPF?
I'm fairly new to WPF and have come from Winforms. I'm trying to get two controls, which are left-right of each other, positioned vertically so that the base-line of the text in one is at the same level as the other. They are a button and a checkbox. The checkbox is to the right of the button. They look correct at designtime, but at runtime the checkbox has moved up a few pixels. The two controls are in a horizontally orientated stackpanel.
I'd upload images but company policy won't allow.
XAML snippet:
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button x:Name="btnCopyMX" Grid.Row="0" Width="60" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4, 4" Click="btnCopyMT_Click">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image Width="18" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="..\Resources\Copy.png" />
            <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >Copy</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkIncludeBlankRows" Margin="4,4"
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncludeBlankRows, Mode=TwoWay}">Include blank rows</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>

How do I get:
(a) the checkbox to stay in the same place between designtime and runtime?
(b) to ensure that the text is at the same base-line (in winforms you can position controls and a line would extend out from one control indicating the base-line of the text and you can snap the text base-line of a second control to it)?

WPF doesn't support text baseline alignment. The best you can do is have everything vertically aligned to center.

Gotcha. This now works and designtime and runtime are looking the same. Shame about the text base-line not being a thing as I used that a lot in Winforms, but I get that the whole thing works completely differently. Thank you.

Are you aware of paths?  For most iconography, I use paths with geeometries defined in a resource dictionary merged into app.xaml.  Vectors and very space efficient.

The Button has a VerticalAlignment of "Top", and an explicit Height (and the CB is probably defaulting to "stretch"). That already starts to throw things off in the same "container". And a StackPanel is one of the least "giving" containers when it comes to aligning things. The Grid is your "layout" champion.

@GerrySchmitz - changed to a Grid. Works perfectly. Thanks.
